# Does the NEST API have an indication for the current heating/cooling/standby state

Tags: nest-api

Is there any way to see whether the system is currently heating/cooling/standby?
In other words: what is the color of the display of the thermostat? (red/blue/black)?

I could not see a value for that in the documented API. Can I derive it from a combination of factors?
for example, if hvac-mode=heat and target-temp `>` ambient then it must be heating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Nest do not give this information.

**Update**

Nest Thermostats now has a [`hvac_state`](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/overview#hvacstate) that returns if the device is off, heating, or cooling.

Comment: This is pretty bad.  Almost 2 years ago users started requesting more usage data (more than 10 days).  https://community.nest.com/ideas/1010   Since then more than 2100 users have liked this request but Nest has not delivered and even their API does not make it possible.

Comment: I have added support for hvac_state in the Nest sample application for Android, here you can find fork of the project: https://github.com/karolbe/android-NestDK/

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the status of Heat On/off in order to calculate properly. I monitor the NEST at 1 hz and store the last state (On or Off) as a variable. once you have this info you can use the following logic and it will be accurate:

```
        lastStatus.Contains("Off"))
        {
            if (temp_current < temp_setpoint)
                status = "Heat On";
            else
                status = "Heat Off";
        }
        else if (lastStatus.Contains("On"))
        {
            if (temp_current > temp_setpoint)
                status = "Heat Off";
            else
                status = "Heat On";
        }
        // Do the work....
        lastStatus=status;
```

Note: temp_current and temp_setpoint are returned from the REST http post. Good Luck!